# New to unity please help me

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a button in my hierarchy in Unity 4.6 by adding a UI button, I want to reference to that button using a c# script and change its Interact able value to true.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I didn't know Unity3D UI has Interact member. But if you want to ref the new UI of Unity3D you must first add UnityEngine.UI name space.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
public Button myButton;
//make it public so you can Drag the Button GameObject to the Inspector
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know how to save a button interactable state even when exiting the program

Comment: It depends. If you treat the Data as suppose to be a secured. I would suggest for you to use to get its component data members and GetHash() it. Then store it.

Comment: it is a button prefab to unlock a new level of my game! when the level unlocks i want it to be saved. i mean how can i save a prefab?

Comment: You don't have to, Just simple save a PlayerPrefs then Activate the level depending on your PlayerPrefs Data.

Example.

PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level",2);

void Start(){
    int MyLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level");

    switch(MyLevel){
       case 1 : 
                myButton1.enabled = true;
        break; 
    }
}

Comment: Now add case 2 : myButton2.enabled = true; break; I have to post the comment quickly because of the 5min maximum time to post the comment.

Comment: it worked the button becomes enabled but when i exit the game or go back to another scene! the button goes to be not enabled! it is not saving!

Comment: I suggest for you to add another Question. With your scripts so we can check the problem, this question was last month already and I can't recall the specific problem you're having. We are gladly to help out as long as you take effort on making your question clear and with the scripts provided for us to check.

Comment: sorry but it worked for me now i just used playerprefs.save() method